# Revert a pull request in Azure Devops and it’s history?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

Made the wrong merge to our remote main branch in Azure. I just want it back before I clicked the merge button.

I did a squash commit, if that’s important.

I’m trying a documentation, that tells me to go to this pull request, click revert. But I’m asked for a Target branch and topic branch name.

What do I put? Main, and my old branch (88-change-header-color)? I don’t want any trace of this revert if possible. So can I leave out the revert ending that auto populates?

And then what? Will this leave any history?

Will it delete any previous branches/commits from other dev?

Answer (score 2):

To set your Main branch to the previous pull request commit and omit the current one, commands to run locally :

1. Make sure you are in the Main branch : git checkout main
2. Run git log to identify the previous commit hash : git log -n 5
   [image]
3. Force remove the last commit from your main branch. Here I'm going back to a previous commit. In my example I want to go back to 38fa66d4abf8dbf02c07bcc816bba280e7d8dcf0 : git reset --hard 38fa66d4abf8dbf02c07bcc816bba280e7d8dcf0
   [image]
4. Now run git log again to verify your history. You can see the last commit is no longer in history
   [image]
5. Force push your updated local Main branch to remote : git push origin main --force

This will reflect the changes in your remote branch. And you wont have that particular PR commit in history.

PS : assumed that the merged pull request commit you want to remove is the last commit done in the main branch.

Comment: Does this work even if we’re using a remote repo —azure?

Comment: Yep. ultimately azure repos just uses git so this will work fine. Just clone your remote repo locally and do this. on push, the changes will be reflected in the remote repo as well. Ensure your commit history is fine before you push to origin/remote

Comment: Do you know how to do it on the azure site? By chance?

Comment: Not really sure how to do it in azure site, it might be possible. But its safer to do it locally first before you push your changes to remote. Cause If something goes wrong your remote is not affected. You can verify your git history log to make sure everything is perfect locally before you push and affect your remote. Doing it on the azure site directly wont give you this option.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can verify your log etc.